# Writing a Python class that can only be used as a context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

Is there a way in Python to write a class that will error unless it's used with a with statement?

```
# Okay:
with Foo() as f1:
    f1.func1()
    f1.func2()

# Not okay:
f2 = Foo()
f2.func1()
```

I can do it manually: have `__enter__` set a flag and have every other method check for that flag. But is there a nicer way to do it?

Here's code for the not-so-since way:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._entered = False

    def __enter__(self):
        self._entered = True
        return self

    def _verify_entered(self):
        if not self._entered:
            raise Exception("Didn't get call to __enter__")

    def __exit__(self, typ, val, traceback):
        self._verify_entered()
        print("In __exit__")

    def func1(self):
        self._verify_entered()
        # do stuff ...

    def func2(self):
        self._verify_entered()
        # do other stuff
```

Comment: Do you need for `foo()` to cause the error, or would `f2.func1()` be OK?

Comment: @Blckknght, having Foo() cause the error would be only modestly preferable to having f2.func1() do it

Comment: You could use a decorator or metaclass to apply the checks automatically rather than manually.

Comment: I wrote a decorator to automate this and posted it as an answer on the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30674542/500584 . I agree with the answers below, you're likely better off separating the object you want to use inside the context manager from the context manager itself, rather than actually enforcing the behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, I think that agf has it right in the sense that you could use a metaclass to automate the stuff. However, if I understand the fundamental motivation behind it correctly, I'd suggest a different way.

Suppose you have a `Payload` class you want to protect via a context manager. In this case, you simply create a context manager that returns it:

```
# This should go in a private module.
class Payload(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'payload ctor'

# This should go in the public interface.
class Context(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Set up here the parameters.
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        # Build & return a Payload object
        return Payload()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # Cleanup
        pass

with Context() as f:
    # f here is a Payload object.
```

If you hide `Payload` in a private module, you're good.

Answer (score 3):

You can have your `__enter__` method return a different object than `self` if you don't want a user to be able to call methods on the context manager object itself.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print("In __enter__")
        return Bar()

    def __exit__(self, typ, val, traceback):
        print("In __exit__")

class Bar(object):
    def func1(self):
        print("In func1")

    def func2(self):
        print("In func2")
```

You can of course have the `Foo` and `Bar` classes more tied together than I have for this example. For instance, the `Foo` class could pass itself to the `Bar` constructor in `__enter__`.

Calling `Foo().func1()` will not work for the obvious reason that `Foo` doesn't have any such method. If you wanted `Bar` not to be visible to the user, you could prefix its name with an underscore (hinting that it's internal) or even nest it within the `Foo` class (or even the `__enter__` method, if you really want to be extreme).

Comment: :-) I seem to have come up with the exact same answer as you.