# How to raise an exception if caller forgot to use with-block on context manager method

Tags: python, contextmanager

I have written a function decorated with @contextmanager, that users of my code should call using a with-block. Sometimes they forget that and call it directly.

```
@contextmanager
def foo():
    print("before")
    yield <something>
    print("after")

# correct usage
with foo() as bar:
    pass # or do some actual work using bar

# incorrect usage, just returns a contextlib._GeneratorContextManager object. None of the print statements are executed
foo()
```

I would like to raise an exception, or at least ensure my `print(”after”)` gets executed (or `__exit__` function gets called) if someone makes this mistake.

Edit:

Obviously this is a made up, somewhat unrealistic example. I’m also aware that what I want to do may be impossible, I just wanted to see if someone else had a solution.

In my real case, the ”before” and ”after” are important parts where the most code is executed (making an http request and then logging it, after giving the user the chance to influence what is logged). The actual use case is in Locust, see https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#validating-responses

Comment: I don't think you have any control over this other than documenting the required usage.

Comment: The second isn't truly incorrect usage. Consider `x = foo(); with x:`...

Comment: In any case, you'll notice your example program only prints `before` and `after` once, so your context manager code isn't entered at all. There's no way for code that's not run to do anything.

Comment: Either way – what is your _actual_ context manager here? Would it be possible for it to `yield` an object that's absolutely required to do the "actual work" within? That way it'd be impossible to use it without a `with`.

Comment: @AKX: The OP's *actual* context manager is the decorated `foo()` function — the whole point of `@contextmanager` is that it constructs one for you.

Comment: @martineau I'm aware how the decorator works -- I'm just curious whether the real implementation OP has is e.g. for some resource/client that'd must be properly released, in which case the only way to acquire the client could be that the function yields it.

Comment: I have added some details about my actual use case. Probably the answer is still ”it is impossible”..

Comment: @AKX: The value the decorate funcion is really yielding isn't the context manager either — I don't see how the decorated function could tell if it was being accessed within a `with` clause or not since whatever it does is the same regardless. There may be some clever way to do it, but it's not obvious (and what you were suggesting isn't even feasible).

Comment: @Cyberwiz By writing a class as a context manager you could check for a flag to see if it is used in a "with" statement or not(`__enter__` got called or not), But since this decorator generates the actual context-manager object for you, you are not capable of doing it. I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that literally requires the call to be on the same (logical) line of source code as one starting with `with`. Obviously that's a bit of a limitation, but perhaps not too big of one…

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from functools import wraps
import inspect
import linecache


# Custom exception.
class MissingWithError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, funcname):
        self.funcname = funcname
    def __str__(self):
        return f'"{self.funcname}()" should only be used with "with".'


def require_with(func):
    """Decorator to ensure the func is on source line starting with "with"."""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper():
        if not linecache.getline(__file__,
            inspect.getlineno(inspect.currentframe().f_back)).lstrip(
        ).startswith("with "):
            raise MissingWithError(func.__name__)
        return func()
    return wrapper

# Combine decorators.
require_with_contextmanager = lambda f: require_with(contextmanager(f))


@require_with_contextmanager
def foo():
    """Docstring."""
    print("before")
    yield '<something>'
    print("after")


# Correct usage.
with foo() as bar:
    print(f'{bar}#1') # Do some actual work using bar.

# Also acceptable usage.
with foo() as \
  bar:
    print(f'{bar}#2') # Do some actual work using bar.

# And this, too.
if True:
    with foo() as bar:
        print(f'{bar}#3') # Do some actual work using bar.

# Incorrect usage - raises Exception.
foo()
```

Output:

```
before
<something>#1
after
before
<something>#2
after
before
<something>#3
after
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "require_with.py", line 56, in <module>
    foo()
  File "require_with.py", line 25, in wrapper
    raise MissingWithError(func.__name__)
__main__.MissingWithError: "foo()" should only be used with "with".
```

Idea is an adaptation of [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28518068/355230) to the question:

[How to check if an object is created with `with` statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517238/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-created-with-with-statement)

Comment: Will this work correctly if the with statement spans multiple lines?

Comment: @AKX: Haven't tested is exhaustively, but `with foo() as bar:` split across two lines does.

Comment: Cool stuff! Is the call to linecache.getline(__file__, inspect.getlineno(inspect.currentframe().f_back)) expensive in cpu terms or is it safe to use when the function is being called a lot?

Comment: I have no idea how "expensive" it is other than it takes more cycles than not doing it and how long that is compare to `foo()` itself. Whether that matters is all relative — like they say, an inch isn't very long unless it's on the end of your nose.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case (and maybe others as well, which is why I'm posting this as an answer) I have the ability to check for the problem later on, after it has happened (in my own code, not the user's), making this solution possible:

```
class MyContextManager():
    _unused_contexts = {}

    def __init__(self):
        MyContextManager._unused_contexts[id(self)] = self

    def __enter__(self):
        del MyContextManager._unused_contexts[id(self)]
        return self

    @classmethod
    def raise_if_unused_contexts(cls):
        if cls._unused_contexts:
            raise Exception("Detected missing with-block")
            # In reality you might log some info about the context that was unused

# incorrect usage, in user code
MyContextManager()

# later on, in library code (in my particular case, after an iteration of user code has finished)
MyContextManager.raise_if_unused_contexts()
```

@martineaus 's answer may be the most generally applicable (works in cases where you dont have the ability to call raise_if_unused_contexts() from inside the library), but it feels more hack-y, and without knowing the performance of frame inspection I'm hesitant to use it.

Comment: It appears your solution is dependent upon magically knowing a point in the user's code at which the context manager should have been used or not — which is exactly why I asked for an example of its usage. I think that's is a very significant limitation (besides being something that could have been probably been accomplished with a simple boolean flag).